# I need to understand this code

Tags: php, mysql, function, printf

I found this code online and I want to understand it. I have read the PHP documentation but I have found out that the Stack Overflow community offers better explanations:

```
function mysql_safe_query($query) {
    $args = array_slice(func_get_args(),1);
    $args = array_map('mysql_safe_string',$args);
    return mysql_query(vsprintf($query,$args));
}
```

I figure the function isn't a builtin PHP function. `array_slice` returns a sequence of elements from the array func_get_args with an offset of 1.

I looked up `func_get_args` and it's supposed to return a copy of the given element(array? object)?? and I guess `vsprintf` returns a formatted string, removing the string quotations ''?

Comment: All your questions about what internal PHP functions will do will be answered on http://php.net - please come back after you read the manual with any questions left.

Comment: Call the function like `mysql_safe_query("SELECT name,age FROM tbl WHERE name='%s'", $input_name)` and you get `vsprintf("SELECT name,age FROM tbl WHERE name='%s'", mysql_safe_string($input_name))`. This function is used to avoid SQL injection without repeatedly typing `mysql_safe_string`.

Comment: Read the manual, play with the functions in a test script, and work through line by line.  If someone explains it to you, you'll say "ok great" and then have to go work through it anyway.  Point is, you'll have to put in the legwork, people can only explain so much.

Comment: I'd recommend learning PHP.

Comment: Oh, also do yourself a favor and research PDO instead of `mysql_*`.  It's just as easy but far more secure and just good practice in general.

Comment: You are getting a lot of flak, but here is some more. Sorry, but that's a poor choice of title and doesn't distinguish your question from countless others.

Answer (score 1):

As the function name suggests, it's supposed to help you perform more secure MySQL queries. However, it's based on `mysql_query` which is deprecated. Instead, you should take a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or at least [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Even though the method signature suggests the method only takes one argument, you may actually pass it an arbitrary number of arguments, e.g.

```
mysql_safe_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE gender = '%s' AND city = '%s'",
  "Female", "Denver");
```

The first part, the query, will be in `$query`. All arguments will be accesible using `func_get_args()`. We slice the array up to ignore the query part, so we'll be left with an array `$args` containing "Female" and "Denver". Afterwards, all arguments are filtered through  `mysql_safe_string`, i.e. `mysql_safe_string` is performed on both "Female" and "Denver". Finally, "Female" and "Denver" are inserted into the query and the query is performed.